# Get a field instance's settings

Tags: entities, 8

What's the equivalent of `field_info_instance()` for Drupal 8?

The default field settings are stored as configuration in a file like field.field.ENTITYTYPE.BUNDLE.FIELDNAME.yml, but how do I get their current value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the *entity_field.manager* service, you are able to get an array of BaseFieldDefinition classes. This service is injectable as well, but for copy-paste working code, you can do the following:

```
$bundle_fields = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions($entity_type, $bundle);
$field_definition = $bundle_fields[$field_name];
$catalog_id = $field_definition->getSetting($setting_name);
```

Comment: If you have an entity and are working with that, you can also access the field definitions of your entity object with $entity->getFieldDefinitions().

Answer (score 5):

Using a field instance:

```
$settings = $field->getFieldDefinition()->getSettings();
```

For example, in a field widget:

```
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $element = [];

  // Get the settings.
  $settings = $items[$delta]->getFieldDefinition()->getSettings();

  // ... build render array

  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The most simple way to get field config is to use [EntityTypeManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityTypeManager.php/class/EntityTypeManager/8.2.x).

```
$entity_type = 'node';// node, taxonomy_term, taxonomy_vocabulary, ...
$bundle = 'article';// the content type machine name
$field = 'field_article_tags';// the field machine name

$fieldConfig =  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('field_config')
  ->load($entity_type . '.' . $bundle . '.' . $field);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to get the Type and Label from the field definition.
This did not work:

```
$setting_name = 'label';
$label = $field_definition->getSetting($setting_name);
```

This worked:

```
$label = $field_definition->getLabel();
$type = $field_definition->getType();
```