# How to programmatically get the field cardinality

Tags: 8, paragraphs

Is there any way to get the number of paragraphs' repeating limit for the entity's field which those paragraphs depends on?

I'm writing a code which creates paragraphs according to the data taken from a CSV data and and insert their target ID (and target revision ID) into user fields programmatically.

The repeating limits of paragraphs for each user field differs. 
Some user fields allow paragraphs to repeat only a few times and others expect them to repeat 10 times.

So if my guess was correct it would be useful if I can get the number when collecting data from CSV and that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Probably you find your solution here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191402/get-a-field-instances-settings , except if it's dynamically set with validation criteria on form submit. So you get the field settings, and you search for the right settings, it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, I figured out a way to get the number(cardinality). Hope it helps someone.

```
(array) $user_fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('user', 'user');

foreach ($user_fields as $user_field_name => $user_field_definition) {
    (array) $cardinality = $user_field_definition->get('fieldStorage')->get('cardinality');
}
```

Comment: Instead of the generic `get()` methods, you really should be using the dedicated getters. This is because `get('fieldStorage')` may return NULL if the fieldStorage property has not been initialized yet. This always works: 

`$cardinality = $user_field_definition->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getCardinality();`